# jQuery Mobile not working on Android 5.0+ devices that have Android System WebView 45.0.2454.95 installed

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, android-webview

We have this problem where our application has stopped working on Android 5.0+ devices since the Google released the latest version of Android System WebView 45.0.2454.95.  If we disable this version of the WebView by going to the device settings, apps, Android System WebView and clicking Disable: the application works again.  However this is not satisfactory for some of our customers and we really need to find a fix where it works with the latest version of Android System WebView.

Our application makes heavy use of jQuery and jQuery Mobile.  We currently use jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.0.  We can’t easily upgrade to a newer version.

When a page loads up in the application any method called inside a jQuery selector doesn’t run, e.g.

`$(function() {
    //Your code here
});`

This code successfully executes when the old version of the WebView is used but not when the latest version is used.  Attempting to call the code outside the selector has resulted in other problems.

During my investigations so far, I have discovered the problem seems to come from something in jQuery Mobile as when I remove the reference to jquery.mobile.js, the code then executes again.  However as you might expect the problems then occur due to jQuery Mobile being an integral part of our application.

Does anyone know of any issues with jQuery Mobile on the latest version of Android System WebView that could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled=false;
```

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
</script>

<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```